# 2003 Honda Civic EX won't start

Tags: starter, battery-drain

I have a 2003 Honda Civic EX and it won't start if you disconnect the battery negative then positive let it sit for a couple minutes then reconnect it positive and negative you get all the lights back on the dash everything works till you turn the key over one time then it goes click and all lights disappear till you go back and do the exact same thing with the battery again and it resets it somehow and all the lights come back but till you turn over the key one time and it just goes click and I cannot get it started I do not know what to do with it I took it to the auto parts store they told me that it was an alternator which it didn't happen to be obviously I put in a new alternator and it's still doing the same thing they told me the battery was 100% but when I look in the battery it's actually an open cell it was looked almost dry inside the battery

Comment: Starting problems have almost nothing to do with the alternator because the starter draws its initial energy from the battery alone. Why don't you simply try a jump start to see if the battery is indeed faulty or not?

Comment: Your battery should be full under all cups with electrolytes. You should either have this battery properly serviced. Try putting in a different known good battery in it and see if it starts. If it does, then put your serviced or new battery in it. Then have your charging system checked by a different service. If it doesn't start you will probably find the problems in the battery cable connections. These should be cleaned when doing battery work.

Comment: Have the battery load tested but please go to a different shop than the first one you went to.  I think you'll find that it's bad as you suspect.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What you are describing is when there is an intermittent connection which is disrupted when you turn the key. When you reconnect the battery, it re-establishes the connection. This connection is enough to provide power to the bits and pieces, but as soon as you turn the key to start it, the current needs of the starter overrides this and the breaks the connection. Do as others have stated and have your battery tested, but I'll bet you need to clean all connections at both ends of your positive and negative leads to fix the issue.